Questions about problem 38, chapter 5 in Armstrong's Basic Topology
The problem states: Show that the one-point union of X and Y has the fixed-point property if and only if both X and Y have it.
I have referred to a solution in https://mccuan.math.gatech.edu/courses/4431/blikas.pdf page 94. And the link Fixed point property in topology term(c) also provides the same solution for the "if" direction.
Their big ideas are to construct and prove the fixed-point property of corresponding functions $f:X\rightarrow X$ or $f:X\vee Y\rightarrow X\vee Y$ based on known functions already equipped with the fixed-point property.
However, I encountered confusion when delving into their proof details:

in the "only if" $\rightarrow$ direction, the usage of the glueing lemma seems to be arbitrary since $X$ or $Y$ is not necessarily open or closed in $X\vee Y$; or maybe I missed some information from the problem;
in the "if" $\leftarrow$ direction, why the function $g:X\rightarrow X$ defined from $f:X\vee Y\rightarrow X\vee Y$ is continuous without knowing the topology of $X\vee Y$ and the openness of $X$ or $Y$ inside?

Thanks

Are $X,Y$ assumed Hausdorff? If so, they are closed in $X\lor Y$.

No extra condition is given, I doubt if I have missed some conventions in this book or chapter :/

Alternatively, the gluing lemma can be avoided. Proving directly that $g$ (in the first part) is continuous is quite easy.

Who are the authors of your .pdf? If they are just students, this could explain their clumsy use of the gluing lemma.

I just grab it from the Internet, I think they are written by students since I found lots of errors in other problem solutions.

The useless repetition in the second part of their $(\impliedby)$  (instead of just saying "wlog $f(p)\in X$")  confirms this.


The gluing lemma can be invoked if $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff because in this case, they are closed in $X\vee Y$. But in the general case, it can be avoided, by a simpler argument: if $f:X\to X$ is continuous then the map $h:X\sqcup Y\to X\vee Y$, defined by $h(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in X$ and $h(y)=f(p_X)$ if $y\in Y$, is continuous and maps both $p_X$ and $p_Y$ to $f(p_X)$, hence factors through a continuous map $g:X\vee Y\to X\vee Y$, by definition of $X\vee Y=(X\sqcup Y)/(p_X\sim p_Y)$. (One could even decompose this argument by applying it first to $f={\rm id}_X$.)
If $f:X\vee Y\to X\vee Y$ is continuous and $f(p)\in X$, just compose $f$ on one side with the (continuous!) map $X\vee Y\to X$, defined by factorization of the canonical map $X\sqcup Y\to X$ which fixes every $x\in X$ and maps $Y$ to $p_X$ (which is continuous and maps both $p_X$ and $p_Y$ to $p_X$), and on the other side with the natural map $X\to X\vee Y$.


Thanks a lot, the second part is neat.
